# pandas dataframe replace whole column with object of same size

Tags: python, dataframe, object

I have a dataframe df1 like

```
  A B
1 2 3
2 9 8
```

and an object ob (dtype: object)

```
1 5
2 4
```

replacing column B in the dataframe with `df1['B'] = ob` doesn't work despite all columns of the dataframe are also objects as `df1.dtypes` tells me and they have the same length. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please provide type(ob)

Comment: ob.dtype: object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be difficult to tell you what is going wrong without knowing how the ob object is made, the object dtype has a very broad definition. Replacing a column is easy if you can convert the ob object to a pandas dataframe:

```
t = pd.DataFrame([[2,3],[9,8]],columns = ['A','B'])    
o = pd.DataFrame([[5],[4]])
t['B'] = o
print(t)
```

Yields

```
   A  B
0  2  5
1  9  4
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. Though I had to turn off this message: _A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead_ with `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'` [see here]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can replace a column with another but here's a method to replace values.

```
df['column name'] = df['column name'].replace(['1st old value','2nd old value',...],['1st new value','2nd new value',...])
```